# Using definitive article with an algorithm name

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, articles, definite-article

Assume there is a well know algorithm known as XX. When I refer to it as in the following example, should I use the article or not?

> In this example, we assume a hybrid-mode using XX algorithm

Or,

> In this example, we assume a hybrid-mode using the XX algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how the sentence is constructed, for example:

> I will use the Bresenham circle drawing algorithm.
>
> I will use Bresenham's circle drawing algorithm.

If there are several versions of one type of algorithm, you can use the indefinite article:

> I will use a breadth first search algorithm.

And for a specific version:

> I will use the Dijkstra algorithm.
>
> I will use Dijkstra's algorithm.

The usual rules for articles applies.